# Why are URLs in the form of "http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/mongo+-+The+Interactive+Shell"

Tags: url

What is the `mongo+-+The+Interactive+Shell` part for and why is it that way?  It seems like it is urlencoded from "mongo - The Interactive Shell"

Answer (score 1):

for the same reason the url to this qustion includes `why-are-urls-in-the-form-of-http-www-mongodb-org-display-docs-mongo-theinte`. unencoded spaces aren't valid, and encoded ones (%20) are hard to read, so a more readable alternative  is used.

Comment: Hm... If I recall correctly, "-" is a valid character in a URL (in the sense that you can upload a file with a hyphen-minus character, and can access it by its actual (local) name), whereas "+" is merely an alternative to "%20". So if one woule upload the file "Essays 2010.docx", you could access it by either "Essays%202010.docx", or "Essays+2010.docx", but not "Essays-2010.docx". If you upload a file "Essays-2011.docx", you can only access it by "Essays-2010.docx".

Comment: I want to add that `+` works as %20 in the form submitted data, but not so when it is the file path... as least on some Apache servers.  So www.site.com/file%20list.txt is not the same as file+list.txt.  I guess ultimately, it depends on how the server interpret the incoming request when it sees a GET or POST and a path.

Answer (score 0):

The W3C [reserved the plus sign](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_URI_Recommentations.html) as a shorthand for the space character.  You'll also find the same document codified as [RFC 1630](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/rfc1630.txt).

Comment: please see comment in Paul's post.

Comment: Point taken.  In the case of the OP's URL, it's pretty clear that they're using the full title as a unique identifier for the page.  I see that a lot and find myself questioning the merits of the practice, especially when there are advantages to much shorter URLs.  (This site does the same thing, and I scratch my head over it.)  But that's a topic for another discussion.